# Half-Life 2 BSP Lightmaps

Tags: textures, coordinates, binary-space-partitioning

I'm writing a BSP viewer for a university project. So far I have the main geometry loaded properly, and the PVS working.

Now I'm trying to apply the lightmaps, but I can't seem to get the texture coordinates for the lightmaps calculated properly.

According to here: http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/The_Source_Engine_BSP_File_Format

```
struct texinfo_t
{
    float textureVecs[2][4];  // [s/t][xyz offset]
    float lightmapVecs[2][4]; // [s/t][xyz offset] - length is in units of texels/area
    int flags;                // miptex flags overrides
    int texdata;               // Pointer to texture name, size, etc.
}
```

> The first array of floats is in
>   essence two vectors that represent how
>   the texture is orientated and scaled
>   when rendered on the world geometry.
>   The two vectors, s and t, are the
>   mapping of the left-to-right and
>   down-to-up directions in the texture
>   pixel coordinate space, onto the
>   world. Each vector has an x, y, and z
>   component, plus an offset which is the
>   "shift" of the texture in that
>   direction relative to the world. The
>   length of the vectors represent the
>   scaling of the texture in each
>   direction.
>
> The 2D coordinates (u, v) of a texture
>   pixel (or texel) are mapped to the
>   world coordinates (x, y, z) of a point
>   on a face by:
>
> u = tv0,0 * x + tv0,1 * y + tv0,2 * z
>   + tv0,3
>
> v = tv1,0 * x + tv1,1 * y + tv1,2 * z
>   + tv1,3
>
> (ie. The dot product of the vectors
>   with the vertex plus the offset in
>   that direction. Where tvA,B is
>   textureVecs[A][B].
>
> Furthermore, after calculating (u, v),
>   to convert them to texture coordinates
>   which you would send to your graphics
>   card, divide u and v by the width and
>   height of the texture respectively.

So I am doing the calculation as follows. Take the dot product of the vertex and the lightmap vector(lightmapVecs[0][0], lightmapVecs[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5hP.png), lightmapVecs[0][2]) add the offset (lightmapVecs[0][3]), subtract the mins, and divide the result by the width/height.

```
float s = Vector3f.dot(v, new Vector3f(lightmapVecs[0][0], lightmapVecs[0][1], lightmapVecs[0][2])) + lightmapVecs[0][3] - f.LightmapTextureMinsInLuxels[0];
float t = Vector3f.dot(v, new Vector3f(lightmapVecs[1][0], lightmapVecs[1][1], lightmapVecs[1][2])) + lightmapVecs[1][3] - f.LightmapTextureMinsInLuxels[1];
s /= (f.LightmapTextureSizeInLuxels[0] + 1);
t /= (f.LightmapTextureSizeInLuxels[1] + 1);
```

However it ends up looking like this:
[image: lightmaps]

Here's a sample calculation for the texture coord 't' for one vertex.

```
vertex = 352.0, -144.00027, -224.0
lightmap vector = -4, 0, 0
lightmap offset = 0
lightmap mins = 9
lightmap height = 14
```

So the dot product is -1408

```
(-1408 + 0 - 9) / 14

t = -101.21
```

This seems way off.

Comment: If you can post a picture link in the comments, someone can edit it in for you.

Comment: Thanks. I got a few vote ups so i can post pictures now. :)

Comment: Why are you dividing by 14? Is your lightmap's size really "14"? Most lightmaps are powers of 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out, I was reading the data in wrong. All the code above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize the vectors before calculating the dot product.